# interpolation of 3D data

Tags: interpolation

I have a 3D surface given in data-points of the form ${x,y,z}$. What is the easiest way to get the interpolated value $z=f(X,Y)$ for given coordinates ${X,Y}$ (which are of course not in the data list)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mathematica's interpolation function, [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html), works on multidimensional data. For example,

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 1];
int = Interpolation[data];
```

Then, you can extract the values for values between the data points:

```
int[1.1, 1.1]
(* ==> 2.42 *)
```

And `Plot3D`, or whatever else you want.

```
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that the interpolation is pretty good:

```
exact[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
int[1.1, 1.1] == exact[1.1, 1.1]
(* => True *)
```

Or better yet (thanks @rcollyer):

```
(int[1.1, 1.1] - exact[1.1, 1.1])/exact[1.1, 1.1]
(* 1.83508*10^-16 *)
```

---

**Update** Leonid's comment below pointed out that the accuracy of `Interpolation` will be worse with an unstructured grid. For example:

```
dataDelete = Delete[data, RandomInteger[{1, Length[data]}]]
intD = Interpolation[dataDelete]
```

Then,

```
(intD[1.1, 1.1] - exact[1.1, 1.1])/exact[1.1, 1.1]
(* ==> 0.0743802 *)
```

which is worse. It seems particularly bad close to the origin:

```
Plot3D[(intD[x, y] - exact[x, y])/ exact[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What's the value of `int[1.1, 1.1] - exact[1.1, 1.1]`? That gives a better indication of fitness then `Equal`.

Comment: +1. Note that `Interpolation` only works on structured grids, while on unstructured ones the interpolation order will be reduced to 1, which in most cases will not be good enough. Try deleting one of the points from your regular grid to see what I mean.

Comment: @rcollyer Good call. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin right, and to get use an unstructured grid, one must rely on splines, likely [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NURB). I have not used the mma functionality for that, though.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Wow, it's _much_ worse on an unstructured grid. I wonder if there's a (good) way to fill in the missing element to create a structured grid such that the interpolation is only really bad near the refilled grid point.

Comment: @EliLansey My guess is that this would depend on how unstructured a grid is. If it is mostly structured, but missing a few points, those points can probably be added using a linear interpolation to compute them, as a bootstrap. If, however, all grid is irregular, then some other method is obviously needed.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Any idea how to figure out where the grid is missing points? Because then you could interpolate to first order, use that the fill the hole, then interpolate to higher order.

Comment: @EliLansey This sounds like a good candidate for a separate question :).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin [Good idea](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/improved-interpolation-of-mostly-structured-3d-data)

Comment: Please, if someone could help me with a closely related question... I may be experiencing a problem with interpolation of 3d data for x and y organized logarithmically. Is this the case of an "unstructured grid"?

Answer (score 17):

`Interpolation`. Let's create some 100x3 data matrix, coloumns representing x, y and f(x,y), covering the domain from [1,10], sampled at the integers for both x and y

```
data = Join[Tuples[{Range[10], Range[10]}], RandomReal[20, {100, 1}], 
   2];
```

Now, I have to apply `Interpolation` to the data, but after grouping it as a list of `{{x, y}, f[x,y]}` values

```
f = Interpolation[Through@{Most, Last}[#] & /@ data];
```

You can use `f` as a regular function, if you keep inside the bounds of your sampling.

Let's see the results graphically

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice visualization of the interpolation with the original data.

Comment: +1 for `Through@{Most,Last}` ... I need to remember that for grouping!