# Doing an Interpolation through a list of lists into a single function

Tags: interpolation

Suppose I have a list of lists, i.e.

```
list = Table[{x, x^ k}, {k, 1, 10}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}];
```

and I want to interpolate each of the lists by a function using `Interpolation` (or another appropriate function). Is there a way to create a function of `k` and `x`, i.e

```
Table[interpFunct[k] = Interpolation@list[[k]],{k,1,10}]
```

so I have `interpFunct[1,x]`, `interpFunct[2,x]`, etc. available?

I know I can interpolate the surface but the mesh is not structured, which [leads to new difficulties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4776/1024) that have nothing to do with my needs.

Any advice will be very helpfull.

Comment: You just need to tell it what to do with the second argument: `Table[interpFunct[k, x_] = Interpolation[list[[k]]][x], {k, 10}]`

Comment: @wxffles Crap, I knew my q. was kinda lame. Thanks a lot. Two things (lame as well): 1. Is there a way to define the domain of interpolation? 2. Even though it is a dumb question, I'll accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Can I suggest to @wxffles to post and answer instead of a comment, no matter how "trivial"? It helps everybody 8^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments here's an answer, plus some variations:

```
Table[interpFunct[k, x_] = Interpolation[list[[k]]][x], {k, Length[list]}]

(interpFunct[#, x_] = Interpolation[list[[#]]][x]) & /@ Range[Length[list]]

Scan[(interpFunct[#, x_] = Interpolation[list[[#]]][x]) &, Range[Length[list]]]

MapIndexed[(interpFunct[#2[[1]], x_] = Interpolation[#1][x]) &, list]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd normally use `Scan[]` for the purpose of building a bunch of functions, but the indexing makes the use of `MapIndexed[]` so tempting:

```
list = Table[{x, x^k}, {k, 1, 10}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}];

MapIndexed[With[{k = First[#2]}, interpFunct[k] = Interpolation[#1]] &, list];

Plot[Table[interpFunct[k][x], {k, 10}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plots of interpolants]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. With all this new functions, I've a lot of reading to do!