# How to get a function from a numerical integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, variable

I wold like to know how to get a function from a numerical integration. Here is an example:

```
h[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[y*Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 1, 2}]
h[2]
```

Then my output will be 1.6329, but I'm looking for a way to get a function of y, with no need to give a numerical value to the variable. In this case my function should be:

```
h[y_]=0.81645*y
```

That is an easy example. Actually I have the following situation:

```
E1=200000;
t=2;
v=0.3;
phi=1
Dp = (E1*t^3)/(12*(1 - v^2));
j1 = 2;
Do[w[m1, n1] = ToExpression["w" <> ToString[m1] <> ToString[n1]], {m1,
    1, j1}, {n1, 1, j1}];
disp[x_, y_, w11_, w12_, w21_, w22_] = 
  Sum[Sum[w[m1, n1]*Sin[m1*(Pi*x/a + Pi/2)]*
     Sin[n1*(Pi*y/b + Pi/2)], {n1, 1, j1}], {m1, 1, j1}];
U[w11_, w12_, w21_, w22_] = ((Dp*a*b*Pi^4)/(8*a^4))*
   Sum[Sum[(w[m1, n1]^2*(m1^2 + phi^2*n1^2)^2), {n1, 1, 
      j1}], {m1, 1, j1}];
V1[Ny_?NumericQ, w11_?NumericQ, w12_?NumericQ, w21_?NumericQ, 
  w22_?NumericQ] := (-t/2)*
  NIntegrate[
   NIntegrate[
    Evaluate[
      N1[Ny, x, y]]*(D[disp[x, y, w11, w12, w21, w22], x])^2, {x, -b/
      2, b/2}], {y, -a/2, a/2}]
V2[Ny_?NumericQ, w11_?NumericQ, w12_?NumericQ, w21_?NumericQ, 
  w22_?NumericQ] := (-t/2)*
  NIntegrate[
   NIntegrate[
    Evaluate[
      N2[Ny, x, y]]*(D[disp[x, y, w11, w12, w21, w22], y])^2, {x, -b/
      2, b/2}], {y, -a/2, a/2}]
V3[Ny_?NumericQ, w11_?NumericQ, w12_?NumericQ, w21_?NumericQ, 
  w22_?NumericQ] := (-t)*
  NIntegrate[
   NIntegrate[
    Evaluate[
      T3[Ny, x, y]]*(D[disp[x, y, w11, w12, w21, w22], x])*(D[
       disp[x, y, w11, w12, w21, w22], y]), {x, -b/2, b/2}], {y, -a/2,
     a/2}]
```

The functions N1, N2 and T3 come from another notebook and are working well. The point is, I need to derive the sum of functions U, V1, V2 and V3 in relation to w11, then I must derive the same sum in relation to w22, and so on. In the end, these resulting functions must be organized in a matrix.

Comment: `Integrate[]`? -- You say it's difficult (well, complex), but difficult situations often need solutions tailored to the situation. Without a representative example, it's hard to say.

Comment: `how to get a function from a numerical integration` you can't. As Michael says, you need to try `Integrate`. But `sin(sin(x))` is really hard to integrate analytically.

Comment: @user70148, i think you simply forgot to  set values for a and b. With that your code should work. (Of course i don't know if the N1,N2, T 3 are friendly)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as I see you need to interpolate.
For your simple example:

```
 h[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[y*Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 1, 2}]
 h1 = Interpolation[Table[{y, h[y]}, {y, 1, 10, .01}], 
      Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2]
 h[2]==h1[2]
 (*True*)
```

h1 is your function

Comment: I think it worked, but what did you exactly did? What means the {y, 1, 10, .01}? And what if I have 2 or more variables?

Comment: Please check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18210/interpolating-2d-data-with-missing-values

Comment: @user70148 Why don't you simply `c= NIntegrate[Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 1, 2}]` followed by `h[y_]:=c y` ?