# Interpolation of mostly-structured 3D data

Tags: bugs, interpolation

this question relates to [interpolation of 3D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/interpolation-of-3d-data) and [Improved interpolation of mostly-structured 3d data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/improved-interpolation-of-mostly-structured-3d-data)

I have an irregular 3d data set that is quite large (around 70,000 triplets---let's call it `Data1`). `ListPointPlot3D[Data1]` gives

[image: list point plot of data]

Clearly, the characteristic feature of this set is that its resolution differs vastly from one direction to the other so that main information for the data lies in thirty stripes of $> 2000$ points each. I have issues with creating an interpolation for this dataset for the reasons mentioned in the other two posts so I would like to "normalise" my grid so that this becomes interpolatable.

At this stage, I'd be happy to get even linear interpolation along the non-dense direction but running `Interpolation[Data1]` just crashes the Kernel.

What I thought of doing was split the strips via `FindClusters`, find the one with the least elements and then reduce the elements of the rest by dropping elements (I can afford to lose some information at the edges) but I don't really know how to implement the right distance in `FindClusters`.

The default Euclidean distance obviously doesn't work:
the $(x, y)$ coordinates of the set forced to split in thirty clusters gives

`Take[#, 2] & /@ Data1;`
`FindClusters[%, 30];`
`ListPlot[%]`
[image: clustered_data]

So my question is two-fold:

- How to implement the distance that would cluster the data properly?
- Can you think of a better way to regularise the grid so as to be able to interpolate this data set?

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tghd4i135svp77v/math_stackovfl.dat) a link to part of the data.

----**EDIT**----

I managed to solve my problem but I'll keep the question open in case anyone would care to improve.

For the record, the [Non-Grid Interpolation Package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7760/) looks really good but didn't really help here - I gave up on the Delaunay triangulation after 15' of evaluation time and the nearest neighbour method didn't look all that good.

So primarily what I did was I straightened the data set (an answer explains one way to obtain the angle) and then sorted it and split it to clusters by the $ x $-coordinate:

```
Rot[x_] := {{Cos[x], Sin[x], 0}, {-Sin[x], Cos[x], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
RotData = Rot[.10795 Pi].# & /@ Data1;
RotData = SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ (RotData~GatherBy~(Round[First@#, 165]&)~SortBy~First);
```

(don't ask how I chose to round to 165!).I then added a missing stripe by averaging:

```
Mean@(RotData[[1]] + RotData[[2]]);
RotData = Insert[RotData, %, 2];
```

Following that, I calculated the domain where all data take values and defined a resolution and step for future reference:

```
lowlimit = Max@(Min /@ (Map[#[[2]] &, RotData, {2}]));
upplimit = Min@(Max /@ (Map[#[[2]] &, RotData, {2}]));
resolution = 2200;
step = (upplimit - lowlimit)/resolution;
```

And I finally created interpolating functions along each cluster and ran a loop to get them to evaluate to points on a regular grid. This wouldn't work if I didn't average over the x-coordinate but for this dataset this gives a very small error.

```
Table[Module[{TempXData, TempInterpData, t},
    TempXData = Evaluate@RotData[[j]];
    TempInterpData = Drop[#, 1] & /@ TempXData;
    t = Interpolation[TempInterpData, Method -> "Spline"];
    Table[{Mean@(First /@ TempXData), y, t[y]}, {y, lowlimit,upplimit,step}]], {j, 1, Length[RotData]}];
IntData = Flatten@%~Partition~3;
```

Now, `IntData` is an interpolatable set:

[image]

So (in the hope this can be useful to someone *OTHER* than myself) if you run into a dataset you can't interpolate, you might want to think about "striping it", Interpolating the stripes and then using the interpolation to populate a regular grid.

Comment: Can you post some sample data to play with please?

Comment: There was [a question where I had to "straighten" a lattice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6832482/695132).  I'm wondering if we can do the same here, then interpolate, then transform back to the original cooridnates.

Comment: Yes, giving a link to the data set would be very good, then I can check if the crash is fixed in the development version.

Comment: Yep - I've uploaded a sample of the data. I remember trying to straighten it at some point but that wasn't really the issue. In any case, the angle was a little less than $ \pi /10 $

Comment: I filed the crash as a bug and we hopefully have this resolved soon. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: I can straighten this, but it's not a fully automatic process.  It requires manual inspection and correction at several stages, so I'm not sure it's useful to you (and worth working out fully and writing down).

Comment: Well done! Perhaps you could write down some details about the package, for future user's reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will create the clusters by hand (but quickly), calculate the mean slope and use it to rotate ("straighten") your plot.
Sorry for the unclean code.

```
(*read your file*)l = ReadList["c:\\long.dat", Number];
l1 = Partition[l, 3];
(*xy coordinates*)
l3 = l1[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
(*Clusterization by hand
using the fact that points are sequentially listed*)
pp = Mean[EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[l3, 2, 1]];
i = 1; j = 2;
s = {};
AppendTo[s, {l3[[1]]}];
While[j <= Length@l3, 
  If[Norm[l3[[j - 1]] - l3[[j]]] < 20 pp, AppendTo[s[[i]], l3[[j++]]],
    i++; AppendTo[s, {l3[[j++]]}]]];
ListPlot@s
(*Mean Slope*)
ms = ArcTan@Mean@(Coefficient[#, x, 1] & /@ Fit[#, {1, x}, x] & /@ s);
l4 = Map[RotationMatrix[-ms].# &, s, {2}];
ListPlot@l4
```

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks (+1). I actually managed to do this just now too. Once I got the angle (which for my accuracy was $0.10795 \pi$ I used `(rot[0.10795 \[Pi]].# & /@ Data1)~GatherBy~(Round[First@#, 165] &)`. It's really clumsy as rounding to 165 was chosen as the number that produces 30 sublists, but it works. I will make an edit tomorrow as I am not sure how to proceed for interpolating. I am favouring creating an interpolation for each line and then using this to populate a regular grid.

Answer (score 7):

I was going to update my other answer, but just found this:

### Non-Grid Interpolation Package

Seems nice ... let's see if it can cope with your large dataset.