# Interpolation of multidimensional data organized logarithmically

Tags: interpolation, logarithmic-scale

The following threads call our attention to the fact that "accuracy of Interpolation will be worse with an unstructured grid", in the context of interpolation of 3d data:

[interpolation of 3D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/interpolation-of-3d-data/4772#comment13129_4772)

[Improved interpolation of mostly-structured 3d data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/improved-interpolation-of-mostly-structured-3d-data)

I want to know if there is a systematic way to do the interpolation correctly for a 3D data with the points distributed logarithmically along x and y.

**Simple example**

The xy grid would be built using

```
grid = Table[ {10^t, 10^u}, {t, 1, 3, 0.05}, {u, 1, 3, 0.1}]
ListPlot[ grid ]
```

[image: Logarithmic grid]

Of course, in logarithmic scale it looks fine (linear):

```
ListLogLogPlot[ grid ]
```

[image]

The 3D data would be built using some 2 variable function `func`:

```
tabx = Table[10^w, {w, 1, 3, 0.05}]
taby = Table[10^w, {w, 1, 3, 0.1}]
tab = Table[ {{x,y},func[x, y]}, {x, tabx}, {y, taby}]
```

Then, how to interpolate `tab` properly?

Comment: Just using `Interpolation` works fine and gives high-order interpolation, although you have to use `Flatten[tab, 1]` to get rid of the nesting. It seems Mathematica still considers your data a structured grid, because it still has the structure of a full grid even though the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are nonuniformly sampled.

Comment: [link](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~fox/NewCCS/ModuleIV/ModIVP5.html) This was very helpful to me. And I guess just find the log to get the uniform grid then organize the data as shown in the link.

Comment: I don't see any difference between using `Interpolation` and `ListInterpolaton` for multidimensional data. Is there any difference? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Nevertheless, your point about doing the interpolation on the uniform grid is good.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why I bother to leave comments.

Comment: Dear Mr. Narain, if you believe your comment corresponds to the final answer, please add it as an **answer**. I assume you haven't got your 3k reputation with politeness.