# Interpolation of 4D data

Tags: interpolation

To create a table and an interpolation function of 3D data T=f(X,Y) I have the answer here: [interpolation of 3D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/interpolation-of-3d-data)

How to create a table/interpolation function of 4D data T=f(X,Y,R)?

If I do

```
dada = Flatten[Table[{x, r, t, func[x, r, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 0.12}, {t, 0, 
 1}], 1];
intfunc=Interpolation[data];
```

doesn't work. func[x,r,t] is a valid function for this domain. I think it has to do with Flatten.

Comment: You need learn about [Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html?q=Interpolation)

Comment: In the same way; add a `R` component to your `Table`.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example interpolation of 4D data:

```
Interpolation[Join[#, {RandomReal[]}] & /@ Tuples[Range@10, 3]]
```

For `Interpolation` to treat the indexing as regular the indices must be in ascending order, with the right-hand side iterating first (e.g. `{1,1,1}`, `{1,1,2}`, `{1,1,3}`). Note that `Tuples` is automatically in the right order if the provided array is in the right order.

**Edit:** Your code is almost correct, except that you should Flatten to the second level, not the first. Also by default `Table` will use "1" as its step-size, you need to specify the step-size if the step is going to be different from 1. Note that Interpolation will throw a warning about reducing the order because you only have 2 points per dimension.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, r, t}, RandomReal[]},
               {x, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 0.12, 0.12}, {t, 0, 1}], 2];
intfunc = Interpolation@data;
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillochon. I think it isn't so easy to learn the Flatten command just reading the documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html